# C# Portable Class Library - How do you include System.Data.Linq

Tags: c#, windows-phone, portable-class-library

Is it possible to reference the System.Data.Linq in a Portable Class Library project?

**Note:**
I am just trying to share code between a WP8 and WinStore8 app [DataContext]

Comment: `System.Data.Linq` is Linq-To-SQL. I seriously doubt that is available outside the Windows Desktop world (I.E Silverlight, or Windows Phone).

Comment: wish i had seen this last week

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No it is not. The Data namespace is unavailable in PCLs.

You can tell because http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.aspx none of its members have the PCL icon, and it is not listed on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx